# Why does destructure renaming cause errors in TypeScript/React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm very new to TypeScript and got this Error which I failed to decipher: `JSX element type 'Controls' does not have any construct or call signatures.`
I tried going through the docs but only got more confused. If I render it as `DefaultControls` it worked but not when I use the destructure rename syntax. How to fix this Error?

```
import * as React from "react";
import DefaultControls from "../comps/DefaultControls";

interface IProps {
  picturesAmount?: number;
  amount?: number;
  controls?: React.ReactNode;
}

class ImageShow extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {
  public static defaultProps = {
    controls: DefaultControls
  };

  public outer: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> = React.createRef();

  public render() {
    const { controls: Controls } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="image-show" ref={this.outer}>
          <Controls />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default ImageShow;
```

and the controls component

```
import * as React from "react";

interface IControlsProps {
  onBackClick: () => void;
  onNextClick: () => void;
}

const DefaultControls: React.SFC<IControlsProps> = props => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={props.onBackClick}>{"<"}</button>
    <button onClick={props.onNextClick}>{">"}</button>
  </React.Fragment>
);

export default DefaultControls;
```

Comment: Can you show your `Controls` interface or whatever is it.

Comment: @zishe do you mean the component? added it

Comment: I think that if you define `defaultProps: IProps` you will see an error. I don't think that a class name actually counts as `React.ReactNode` and I don't think you can use `ReactNode` like this. A react node would be used as `{controls}`.